# Why stopping at generating a PGP key when building kernel?

Tags: centos, kernel, gnupg

When I build CentOS6 kernel, it stops at the following steps:

```
###
### Now generating a PGP key pair to be used for signing modules.
###
### If this takes a long time, you might wish to run rngd in the background to
### keep the supply of entropy topped up.  It needs to be run as root, and
### should use a hardware random number generator if one is available, eg:
###
###     rngd -r /dev/hwrandom
###
### If one isn't available, the pseudo-random number generator can be used:
###
###     rngd -r /dev/urandom
###
+ gpg --homedir . --batch --gen-key /home/build/rpmbuild/SOURCES/genkey
gpg: WARNING: unsafe permissions on homedir `.'
gpg: keyring `./secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `./pubring.gpg' created
```

Even wait for several hours, the build script won't go on. Have I must manually run rngd?

I built the kernel for several times, and only had once to successfully finished this step.

Comment: The same trouble on RHEL 6.4, kernel 2.6.32-358.11.1, rpm-build-3.8.0-32.

Answer (score 2):

The output text tells you exactly what is going on: There isn't enough entropy to generate the GPG keys needed.

You can either run rngd as suggested, or you could try doing something like 'sudo find /'.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed quite old package rng-utils-2.0-5.el5.x86_64.rpm on RHEL 6.4, hanged it on a /dev/urandm and managed to get gpg keys.